# Crash trying to delete object or particle system

Tags: objects, particles

I have updated a project from 2.79 where there is a plane with a particle system on it.

Every time I try to do anything to the plane it crashes Blender right away. Sometimes even selecting it makes it crash. When I try to go to *Edit Mode*, it crashes, I try to <kbd>G</kbd>  move or <kbd>R</kbd> rotate, it crashes.

I tried to delete the particle system that's on it but it makes it crash too.

Basically I cannot do anything with it and cannot get rid of it.

Any idea what could be the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*Any idea what could be the problem?*" > "Converted" projects between major versions

Comment: Hi Duarte, thanks for your answer. And is there any fix to it? Is there any way to get rid of the plane or particle system when I already updated to 2.8?